# Ansible: main.yml in main folder must not be empty

Tags: ansible

Scenario: To add additional .yml files in defaults or vars in a role without including them on role level we need to add a main folder to eg. defaults --> role/defaults/main/main.yml -->eg. role/defaults/main/test.yml is also processed and automatically included in this role

However if the main.yml inside the main folder is empty(no variables declared etc.) no other yml files in the main folders are processed by ansible. Possible error: Undefined Variable

Is this a bug or intended behaviour?

Comment: The [fix](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/54559) has already been merged. You might want to delete this question after the next release.